# Similar codes output different results

Tags: c, floating-point, double

The output of the following code is `0.0000000`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float x;
    x = (float)3.3 == 3.3;

    printf("%f", x);

    return 0;
}
```

Whereas this code outputs `1.000000`:

```
int main() { 
    float x; 
    x = (float)3.5 == 3.5; 

    printf("%f", x); 

    return 0; 
}
```

The only difference between the 2 codes is the value in the comparison, however, the results are not the same, why is this?

Comment: in this code output is 1.   int main(){
float x;
x=(float)3.5==3.5;
printf("%f",x);
return 0;
}

Ans 1.00 // why in this output is 1

Comment: Code should be in the question, not in the comments.

Comment: Maybe the second `3.3` is `double` which has a different bit representation.

Comment: The value `3.3` cannot be represented exactly in floating point.  When `3.3` is cast to `float`, some precision is lost.  When the result is compared to `3.3`, which is a `double` constant, it is converted back to `double`, but the lost precision is not regained, so the two values compare unequal.

Comment: Constants are double.  So the cast to float loses precision.

Comment: Note that `(float)3.3==3.3` is equivalent to `((float)3.3)==3.3`, which may not be what you intended.  The result of the comparison is an integer, which is implicitly cast to `float` when the assignment is made.  This is quite different from `(float)(3.3==3.3)`.

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
x=(float)3.3==3.3;
```

Compares `(float)3.3` and `3.3` for equality and assigns the result to `x`.  The left side of the comparison has type `float` because of the cast, while the right side has type `double` which is the default type for floating point constants.

The value 3.3 cannot be represented exactly in binary floating point, so the actual value stored is an approximation.  This approximated value will be different for types `float` and `double` due to their differing precisions, so the equality will evaluated to false, i.e. 0.  This is the value that gets assigned to `x`.

Regarding your comment on why `x` is 1 when the number you're checking is 3.5, that is because 3.5 *can* be represented exactly in binary, and both types have the precision to store that value, so they compare equal.

Answer (score 2):

The assigned value `3.3` is a type of `double` but you're trying to compare a `double` with a `float` (by typecasting and due to this, precision losses).

The value of `3.3` as `double` is 3.299999999999999822 whereas the same value in `float` is measured 3.299999952F which are clearly unequal. Hence, the result will be true (i.e. 1.0000000) if you typecast the other `3.3` as `float`.

Rather than:

```
x = (float) 3.3 == 3.3; // float != double precision (precision loss)
```

If you do this:

```
x = (float) 3.3 == (float) 3.3; // converting both to make precision equal
```

Or,

```
x = (double) 3.3 == (double) 3.3; // converting . . . (same)
```

In other words, the comparison will be equal if you convert any one of the expression as same as the other one.

Also, notice that `3.5` is equal to 3.50000000... in both `float` and `double`, hence all the trailing zeroes are truncated from the assigned variable and hence you get 1.0000000. But this stuff is just a bit contrary with `3.3`.

Answer (score 2):

`float` has less precision than `double`, the value of `3.3` constant defaults to double and is [`3.299999999999999822`](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=051046051), the same constant when converted to [`float` is `3.29999995231628418`](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=051046051).

`3.299999999999999822 == 3.29999995231628418` the result of this comparison is `false` i.e. `0`.

Given the precedence rules, the expresssion amounts to `x = ((float)3.5 == 3.5);`, the comparison is evaluated first and the result is assigned to `x`.

When there is no cast both constants default to `double` so naturally the result of the comparison between them is `true` i.e. `1`.

Regarding the comparison between `3.5` `double` and `float` being `true`, it has to do with [the binary conversion](https://ryanstutorials.net/binary-tutorial/binary-floating-point.php), `3.3` is subjected to an aproximation given the fact that the mantissa conversion would go on indefinitely as can be seen in the [link above](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=051046051), the exact value simply cannot be represented in `double` nor in `float`, whereas `3.5` is perfectly representable both [in `double`](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=051046053) and [`float` alike](https://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=051046053).

Answer (score 1):

To see loss of precision with float:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    float x = 3.3;
    double d = 3.3;
    printf("%12.9f %12.9lf\n",x, d);
```

Output:

```
 3.299999952  3.300000000
```

Answer (score 1):

3.3 in binary is

```
11.0100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
```

When converted to `float` some bits of precision are truncated

```
11.0100110011001100110011001100110
```

When converted back to double, computer just uses `0`'s

```
11.0100110011001100110011001100110000000000000000
```

So

```
3.3                     11.0100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
(float)3.3              11.0100110011001100110011001100110
(double)((float)3.3)    11.0100110011001100110011001100110000000000000000
```

---

3.5 for comparison

```
3.5                     11.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
(float)3.5              11.1000000000000000000000000000000
(double)((float)3.5)    11.1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Values like `3.3` cannot be represented *exactly* in a finite number of bits, just like the result of `1/3` cannot be represented exactly in a finite number of decimal digits, so you wind up storing an approximation of the value.

The `float` approximation is different from the `double` approximation, so the comparison `(float) 3.3 == 3.3` fails.

By contrast, `3.5` *can* be represented exactly in both `float` and `double` types, so the comparison `(float) 3.5 == 3.5` succeeds.

Just like with integer types, the significand of a floating-point type is a sum of powers of 2 - the value `3.5` is represented as `1.75 * 21`, and the binary representation of the significand `1.75` is `1.112` - `1 * 20 + 1 * 2-1 + 1 * 2-2`, or  `1 + 0.5 + 0.25`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you loose precision when converting the value `3.3`, which is a literal of type `double`, to a float value with the cast `(float)3.3`. This loss of precision is irreversible, even if the comparison operator `==` will promote the left operand back to type double.

So the issue is that

```
(double)((float)3.3) == (double)3.3
```

will be false since the cast of `3.3` to `float` looses precision. For `3.5`, in contrast, the result will be `true`, because 3.5 can be exactly represented as `float` in the same precision as `double` can.

Actually, the situation can be compared to casting a value from a higher rank to a lower and then back like in the following snippet:

```
unsigned int x = 257;
unsigned char y = x;
unsigned int x2 = y;
printf("%d\n", x==x2);   // 0

x = 255;
y = x;
x2 = y;
printf("%d\n", x==x2);   // 1
```